# Householder QR with column pivoting

Tags: algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, recursive-algorithms

In numerical linear algebra, we know how Householder QR can handle rank deficient matrices with column pivoting: which is essentially to choose the left-over columns with the maximum norm and use permutation matrices to put it in front, for instance, see page 18-19 of:

[https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~saad/csci5304/FILES/LecN8.pdf](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Esaad/csci5304/FILES/LecN8.pdf)

Yet, little were known about the justification of this method. I was told that it is discovered and used simply because it worked for the most of the time. I was also told that there are counter-examples where this method fails. Little literature can I find for Householder QR with column pivoting in general not to mention the case when it fails. Could somebody provide some justification and literature on this?

Comment: This is late and I do not know if there is actually an answer here, but I could find some things and further references about Householder QR in the book [Geometric Methods and Applications
For Computer Science and Engineering by J. Gallier](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-9961-0), specifically Section 8.3

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you so much! I will take a look.